# Trello email-to-board doesn't work with Gmail alias

Tags: gmail, trello, alias

Trello's email-to-board works fine with the direct email, but I've set up an a filter in Gmail to forward mails to it, and it fails. There's no bounced email, but I don't see anything show up on Trello.

How then can I set up an alias on my domain to forward to a Trello board?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem by setting up a Gmail filter forwarding to Trello's email-to-board address. It worked fine for me. Are you sure you confirmed the forwarding address? Also, what do you mean by "Gmail alias" and what does the question have to do with your domain?